# Django Dynamic filtering for ListView not working

Tags: django, django-views

Filtering ListView

Hi, I am trying to follow the documentation but I just get a page not found using this system. This is what they say to do:

```
# urls.py
from django.urls import path
from books.views import PublisherBookList

urlpatterns = [
    path('books/<publisher>/', PublisherBookList.as_view()),
]


# views.py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import ListView
from books.models import Book, Publisher

class PublisherBookList(ListView):

    template_name = 'books/books_by_publisher.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.publisher = get_object_or_404(Publisher, name=self.kwargs['publisher'])
        return Book.objects.filter(publisher=self.publisher)
```

And here is my version.

url

```
path('<area>', ProjectListView.as_view(), name='project-list'),
```

views.py

```
class ProjectListView(ListView):

    # model = Project

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.area = get_object_or_404(Area, name=self.kwargs['area'])
        return Project.objects.filter(area=self.area)
```

Model is commented out as it does not appear in the documentation version. I am using the template name that ListView gives. I can add models if necessary, but there is little different from the ones in the documentation. What am I doing wrong, or is the Documentation not accurate?

Adding Models:

```
class Area(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, unique=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=45, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Project(models.Model):
    '''
    Main Project, serves the default Projects Portal window.
    '''
    published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=64)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    others = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    deadline = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    priority = models.ForeignKey(Priority, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    closed = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

url I am trying is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/si/Operational Improvement/
```

Operational Improvement being one of the items in the area table. Error just says it can't find page, and includes:

```
si/ <area> [name='project-list']
```

which is the right page, so not sure why it's saying it can't find it. FYI, before I added the dynamic part of the url and added the get_queryset method, the page loaded fine. I need to be able to filter though and that currently doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Edited question to include what you requested.

Comment: Change your path pattern to `'<area>/'`, since you're including the backslash in your URL. The **`str`** pattern only matches non-empty strings excluding the path separator **`/`**

Comment: If that doesn't work, show us the urls.py where the project list pattern is included (the one with `si/`), there's a space in your error that I don't understand.

Comment: As an aside, it’s not a good idea to have spaces in your urls. I suggest you add a slug field to your area model and use that in the URL.

Comment: @dirkgroten Thank you, that fixed it and is doing what is expected, thank you for your help. If you would be kind enough to put your top answer as an answer, I'll mark it as the correct solution.